# DriverResult Editor render custom template in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, orchardcms

I'm working over this module ([Extended Registration](http://extendedregistration.codeplex.com/)). This module provides a simple way of showing custom user fields in the registration.
Overrides the AccountController form user and loads the Editor Template in the Registration template

AccountController

```
        var shape = _orchardServices.New.Register();
        
        var user = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New("User");
        if (user != null) {
            shape.UserProfile= _contentManager.BuildEditor(user);
        }
        
        return new ShapeResult(this, shape);
```

Register.cshtml

```
    </div>
    @if (Model.OERegister != null) {
        <fieldset>
            @Display(Model.UserProfile)
        </fieldset>
    }
    <div>
```

The shape here is the Editor Template (EditorTemplate/Parts/template)

It Works just fine, but I need to hide some fields from the registration form.

I'm kind of lost here, and I want to do it in the most Orchish way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the question here is how to generally hide some fields from a form.

Depending on how the author of the form's code designed it or whether you're the developer, there are multiple ways:

- Have parts of the form in separate shapes, and return their factories in a Combined driver result from a driver. This means, your driver building part of the form by providing the shapes for a part's editor will register multiple shapes (this is similar to what e.g. BodyPartDriver.Display() does: it returns three separate shape registrations). Now these can be individually controlled by placement, so you can also hide them.
- If you have no such fine control over how the form is built, you can still override the shape templates containing the fields you want to hide. Then in the override you can freely customize the look of the form. Beware that unlike the first solution, this won't automatically prevent the user from posting the hidden fields' data to the server, and thus saving it.

BTW I don't think the ContentManager.New() can ever return null. Even if the content type is not statically defined (i.e. created from a migration or through ContentDefinitionManager) it will return a content item.

Comment: Thanks, your answer give me some guidence.